# FreeBSD mount_nullfs lost after reboot

Tags: mount, freebsd

I want to mount one directory to another. For this I am using `mount_nullfs`.

This works fine but when I reboot the mount is gone.
Does someone know how I can keep the directory mounted after a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which mounts a system will perform on startup is defined in the file `/etc/fstab`, so you will need to define your mount here to make it persistant over a reboot. `man fstab` should give you all information needed.